# What do the Schema.org enumerations for MapCategoryType mean?

Tags: google-search, schema.org, microdata

On Schema.org there is a type for marking up a map. I want to include a link to a Google Map showing where my business is located.

There are four options, but I'm not sure which one is appropriate:

```
ParkingMap
SeatingMap
TransitMap
VenueMap
```

Parking, Transit, and Venue all seem like suitable options.

Are these types of things even necessary? I just want to make sure my map is displayed when someone searches my business on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These enumeration URIs can be used as value for the [`mapType` property](http://schema.org/mapType). They simply specify the type/kind of map.

So if you have a [`Map`](http://schema.org/Map), and you want to specify its type, it could look like this:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Map">
  <link itemprop="mapType" href="http://schema.org/TransitMap" />
</div>
```

For Google Search, there doesn’t seem to be any kind of documented feature (at least not on https://developers.google.com/structured-data/ and https://developers.google.com/webmasters/business-location-pages/) that would make use of Schema.org’s `Map` type.

If you simply want to link to a map for a [`Place`](http://schema.org/Place) (e.g., a [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness)), without providing metadata for the map (like the `mapType`, the map name etc.), you could use its [`hasMap` property](http://schema.org/hasMap) and, instead of referencing a `Map` item, provide the direct URL:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
  <a itemprop="hasMap" href="http://example.com/your-map">Map</a>
</div>
```

I guess it’s also conceivable that consumers (like Google Search) might display (their own) maps even without this `hasMap` property to begin with, e.g., based on the [`address`](http://schema.org/address)/[`location`](http://schema.org/location).

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't very clear how to use the URL in conjunction with the hasMap property. Upon further research, I think I have to add my business to [Google Places](https://www.google.com/business/ce/mws/?utm_expid=101497709-8.oQy7-WxnRfuVxAoqagd3-w.1&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bing.com%2F) in order to have the map appear on Search.